Upper bounding the number of lines passing through at least $p$ points in a finite point set
Consider the following definition: for a positive integer $p$, and a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of size greater than $p$, let $t(S, p)$ be the number of distinct slopes among all straight lines passing through at least $p$ points in $S$; further, for a positive integer $q > p$, define $$ T(q, p) := \max_{|S| = q} t(S, p). $$ What kind of upper bounds can we show for $T(q, p)$? I think $$ T(q, 2) = \binom q 2, $$ because it should always be possible to find $q$ points such that none of them is collinear and no two of the lines joining them are parallel to each other (but my geometry is kinda rusty, so I'm not entirely sure). Another trivial observation would be that $T(q, p) = 1$ if $p > q / 2$, because after drawing one line there's not enough points left for more.
The best general bound I have been able to show is $$ T(q, p) \le \frac q p \left \lfloor \frac {q - 1} {p - 1} \right \rfloor. $$ My reasoning is as follows: let $L$ be the set of lines contributing to $T(q, p)$ (i.e., passing through at least $p$ points); since no two lines have more than one point in common, each point $P$ can be on at most $\lfloor (q - 1) / (p - 1)\rfloor$ lines in $L$ (because each of these lines must contain a disjoint set of $p - 1$ points in addition to $P$); if we sum the number of lines passing through $P$ over each $P$, we count each line at least $p$ times; hence the bound follows.
However, I suspect this is not a tight bound, and in reality $T(q, p)$ should become linear in $q$ soon if we start increasing $p$ beyond $2$. But I cannot come up with any good argument for this. Does anyone have a clue? A typically interesting range for $p$ would be $3 \le p \le \log_2 q$. Is there a way to apply the Sylvester-Gallai Theorem here, combined with some combinatorial argument? Alternatively, can you exhibit a construction for $S$ with $t(S, p)$ quadratic in $q$?
A closely related question I found was this, but it doesn't deal with distinct slopes, which is what I need.
(If you already have a nice answer to this, I have a deeper question: how far does this analysis carry over if we replace $\mathbb R$ with a finite field? I don't know what kind of geometric intuition applies there, but we can define the slope of a 'straight line' joining $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ as $(y_2 - y_1) (x_2 - x_1)^{-1}$, and call $p$ points collinear if each straight line joining two of them shares the same slope, so at least we can state the above problem for any field.)
